# Rails 4: Multiple joins with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, many-to-many, has-many-through, eager-loading

The following ERD includes the classes involved in the question.

[image: ER Diagram]

Here are the code of the 3 main classes (Monitoring, Link and Story).

```
class Monitoring < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :keywords, through: :monitoring_keywords
  has_many :monitoring_unread_keywords, -> { order("count asc") } # database view
  has_many :monitoring_keywords, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stories, through: :links
  has_many :links
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :monitoring
  belongs_to :story

  has_many :keyword_links
  has_many :keywords, through: :keyword_links, dependent: :destroy

  scope :unreads, -> { where(viewed: false) }
  scope :rateds, -> { where("rating is not null") }
  scope :sents, -> { where(sent: true) }
  scope :discardeds, -> { where(discarded: true) }
  scope :clickeds, -> { where(clicked: true) }
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keyword_links, through: :links
  has_many :keywords, through: :keyword_links
  has_many :links

  belongs_to :source
end
```

What I want is to get all monitorings, including the keywords and today stories. The following query returns me what I want, but with all stories.

```
# company_id is a column in monitorings
@monitorings = Monitoring.joins(:stories).includes([{ stories: [:source] }, :keywords]).where(company_id: current_company.id)
```

[image: Response]

[Response (original size)](https://i.cloudup.com/eFtw4zn3Dj.png)

I have no idea how to get only the today's stories. If I add to the where method `stories: { created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day }`, rails still get all stories, but only get the monitorings that have at least one story that day.

I also tried to add a net relationship into monitoring like `has_many :stories, -> { where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day) }, class_name: "Story", foreign_key: "story_id"`, but I am not able to make this work.

**MISSING INFORMATION:** Monitoring has a n-1 relationship with Company, and the company_id field in Monitoring is used to filter the result.

Comment: Don't you want to filter on `published_at` rather than `created_at`?

Comment: In this version it really doesn't matter yet, the `published_at` is equals to `created_at`. But filtering on `published_at` doesn't seem to solve the problem, the same thing still happens.

Comment: The output sample you provided is practically impossible to read, at least on my 17 inch laptop monitor.

Comment: I added the [direct link](https://i.cloudup.com/eFtw4zn3Dj.png) to the image now.

Comment: And in what model does company_id is?

Comment: Company has many Monitorings.

Comment: looks like you have multiple questions. Can you please add your question in more conscious way.

Comment: just an observation but if you append to_sql to the end of a query you can get the SQL that would be generated. This is useful while debugging, e.g. pry, versus needing to check the log.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use eager loading (`includes`) and limit the results the [Rails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations) recommend creating a new association. In this case you would need to create a new association in `link.rb`

```
has_many :todays_stories, -> { where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)}, class_name: "Story"
```

and then you could add a new relation in `monitoring.rb`

```
has_many :todays_stories, through: :links
```

Then you could perform the following query (I tweaked it to use the format I use in multitenant environments)

```
@monitorings = current_company.monitorings.includes(:keywords, todays_stories: :source)
```

The following code should return the results you are looking for

```
@monitorings.first.todays_stories
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@monitorings = Monitoring.joins(:stories).includes([{ stories: [:source] }, :keywords]).where(company_id: current_company.id).where('stories.created_at > ? AND stories.created_at < ?', Date.today.beginning_of_day, Date.tomorrow.beginning_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@monitorings = Monitoring.joins(:stories).
               includes([{ stories: [:source] }, :keywords]).
               where(company_id: current_company.id).
               where('stories.created_at > ?', Date.today.beginning_of_day)
```

What I have also done at times is added an additional association that is scoped how I want it to be.

```
class Monitoring < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :keywords, through: :monitoring_keywords
  has_many :monitoring_unread_keywords, -> { order("count asc") } # database view
  has_many :monitoring_keywords, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stories, through: :links
  has_many :new_stories, -> { where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)}, through: :links
  has_many :links
end
```

Then you can do:

```
@monitorings = Monitoring.joins(:new_stories).
           includes([{ stories: [:source] }, :keywords]).
           where(company_id: current_company.id)
```

---

Since the above answer I've come across [this article](https://gorails.com/episodes/named-scopes-with-activerecord-merge) about merge which may do exactly what you want although I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope in  story class
For example if you want story they are created today only then 
you can write

default_scope -> {
  where('created_at > ? ', Time.now.beginning_of_day)
}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what's happening is Rails is doing an inner join on Monitoring and Story, which means you won't get any Monitoring records that don't have an associated Story.

One way to solve this would be specifying a custom clause to `joins`, but according to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) it should happen automatically if you use `includes` with a `where` condition on the joined table (which is what you want to do anyway).

**tl;dr**: Try dropping the `joins` call from your query:

```
@monitorings = Monitoring.includes([{ stories: [:source] }, :keywords]).where(company_id: current_company.id, stories: { created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write join query manually. Try something like that:

```
s = Monitoring.joins(
"inner join links on links.monitoring_id = monitoring.id" +
"inner join stroies on stroies.id = links.story_id"
).where("stroies.created_at = '?'", target_date).includes(:keywords)
```

Sorry if I understood something wrong. Also I can mismatched with singular/plural